# I have a substring error on start index

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keep getting this error in my app
small snippet of how simple this code is suppose to work

```
String lang = "Language.en-US".ToString();
appPath.Text = lang.Substring(2, lang.Length);//
```

Error

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 
Index and length must refer to a location within the string
```

i get an error each time i change the start index but if i set it to 0 it works but i can't change the start index to a higher number than zero is there anything i can download like an update to fix this Im sure it my system thats wrong im using .Net 4.0.

Comment: `String lang = "Language.en-US".ToString();` It is already a string?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change it to

```
appPath.Text = lang.Substring(2, lang.Length - 2);
```

Basically according to the [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) method documenation

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex,
    int length
)
```

`startIndex + length` should be less than the string length.

If you always want to get the string from second position to the very end you should use the overloaded version of **[Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx)** that is

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you give lang.Length as the length of string to extract from index of 2, the range goes out of the string.

It should be

```
lang.Substring(2, lang.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Substring accept two parameters, the first one (*startIndex*) is where to start, it should be a number between 0 and the length of this string (*length*); the second one is the length of this substring, it should between 0 and *length-startIndex*

Answer (score 2):

lang.Length - 1
It's zero based, so your length will outnumber the index

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first parameter is the start position and the second parameter is how many characters to take. Since you are starting at the second position, if you take lang.Length characters that will put you outside the bounds of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers below seems correct (see @parapura rajkumar answer).

But a better option in your case would be to take a look at

[String.Substring Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx)

seeing as you require the entire remainder of the string